# White line on top of menu bar - in Chrome and IE

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, menu, whitespace

In chrome and IE, there is a white line over my menu bar at my site (http://tornaia.com). Here is a screenshot of the site in chrome: (http://tornaia.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=2172&action=edit)

I tried using Firebug Lite to inspect the line, but I can't click on it. The closest thing I have come to a solution, was when I redused the line height to 0. Then the line went away. But of course so did all the text on my site, so it wasn't really a big win :p

Any ideas of what this is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something is wrong with your IE exceptions. It's putting a line break when interpreted in chrome and putting this info into the body instead of above the head. When i delete the line break, your white bar goes away.

see the

"
"

in my screen shot?

[image: see the line break with inspect element in chrome]

After seeing your pastebin, try this

replace lines 16-18 with this code instead

```
<!--[if IEMobile 7 ]> <html <?php language_attributes(); ?>class="no-js iem7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js ie6 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]> <html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js ie7 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]> <html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js ie8 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|(gt IEMobile 7)|!(IEMobile)|!(IE)]><!--><html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="no-js"><!--<![endif]-->
```

then delete the line breaks. line 20 and line 34

Comment: More specifically, remove the line-break after doctype HTML, and remove the space before the open-HTML tag.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your answers! I'm sorry, but I'm not quite sure where I need to go to correct these errors. I use FileZilla, and the closest I came to your screen shot was in the `header.php` - file, which looks lik this: (http://pastebin.com/ek0Z5RuQ), but I can't see the errors there.

Comment: Hi! I did what you said, but no luck. The line is still there. Here is the new version of my `header.php`: (http://pastebin.com/2nwArEwy).

Comment: Hi, I found the issue. It was just a plugin that needed updating. Thanks for helping me out anyway!